# JavaScript no console errors

Tags: javascript, if-statement, calculator

Hello I am trying to do simple arithmetic problem checker. Using if, else, statements. I don't get any errors on the console so I am stuck. I am at a basic level and trying to learn to debug. 
This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Your Math Skills!</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        /*Input: Intergers and arithmatic operator by user.
         *Processing: Compute user's input.
         *Output: Display
        */
        function mathSkills(){

        //Get intigers and arithmatic from user.
        var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("box1")).value;
        var operator = parseFloat(document.getElementById("box2")).value;
        var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("box3")).value;
        var result = parseFloat(document.getElementById("box4")).value;

        //Compute user inputs.

        if(a + b == result){
        window.alert("Correct! Good job.")
        }else if(a - b == result){
        window.alert("Correct! Good job.")
        }else if(a * b == result){
        window.alert("Correct! Good job.")
        }else if(a / b == result){
        window.alert("Correct! Good job.")
        }else{
        window.alert("Incorrect. Try again!")
        }
        }
        //Display message to user.
    </script>
        </head>
            <h1> Test Your Math Skills!</h1>
        <body>
            Number: <input type="text" id="box1" size="3">
            Operation:  <input type="text" id="box2" size="3">
            Number: <input type="text" id="box3" size="3">
            Result: <input type="text" id="box4" size="3">
        <button type="button" onclick="mathSkills()">Check</button>



        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are parsing the element, not the value.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("box1").value);
 var operator = parseFloat(document.getElementById("box2").value);
 var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("box3").value);
 var result = parseFloat(document.getElementById("box4").value);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. I knew that part looked funky but I didn't realize why.